# Pandas: appending all row values based on a value present in list after randomized sampling

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as `df` follows

```
ZZONE    ZRET_QTY    ZREQ_VAL    ACTIVE
BLR        100         22.26       1
BLR        125         25.66       1
BOM        223         29.56       1
BOM        133         26.55       0
BOM        98          18.56       1
BLR        227         29.50       0
```

**Objective:** 
   To have a dataframe where for each `ZZONE` equal number of `1` and `0` are present as `ACTIVE`. Such sampling should be randomized. It should look like

```
ZZONE    ZRET_QTY    ZREQ_VAL    ACTIVE
BLR        100         22.26       1
BLR        227         29.50       0
BOM        223         29.56       1
BOM        133         26.55       0
```

My Approach so far:

```
zone_lst = df['ZZONE'].unique.tolist()
for z in zone_lst:
  df_z_1 = df[(df['ZZONE']==z) & (df['ACTIVE'] == 1)].sample(frac = 0.5)
  df_z_0 = df[(df['ZZONE']==z) & (df['ACTIVE'] == 0)].sample(frac = 0.5)
  df_z_f = pd.concat([df_z_1,df_z_0],axis=0) # <--appending data
```

This is generating a dataframe but only `BLR` is present. In other words, the loop is only taking the first `ZZONE` and then creating the dataframe `df_z_f`.

How to run this loop for all elements in `zone_lst`?

**Edit:**

Please be noted that all `ZZONE` must be present in the final `df`. And for `ACTIVE` as 1 and 0 the sampling fraction (i.e. `frac`) can vary.

Comment: what if there was one more row in it with zzone BLR and active value 0, what should be the output..?

Comment: The output would be same as shown above. I am using `sample` with frac=0.5, thus expecting equal occurance of 1 and 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with `groupby` in custom function:

```
def func(x):

    #count number of each value and return minimal what is passed to n parameter in sample
    same = x['ACTIVE'].value_counts().min()

    a = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 0].sample(same).index
    b = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 1].sample(same).index

    return df.loc[a.union(b)]
```

Another idea:

```
def func(x):

    same = x['ACTIVE'].value_counts().min()
    a = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 0].sample(same)
    b = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 1].sample(same)
    return a.append(b)

df = df.groupby('ZZONE').apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  ZZONE  ZRET_QTY  ZREQ_VAL  ACTIVE
0   BLR       125     25.66       1
1   BLR       227     29.50       0
2   BOM       223     29.56       1
3   BOM       133     26.55       0
```

EDIT:

```
def func(x):
    a = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 0].sample(frac = 0.4).index
    b = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 1].sample(frac = 0.6).index
    return df.loc[a.union(b)]
```

Or:

```
def func(x):
    a = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 0].sample(frac = 0.4)
    b = x[x['ACTIVE'] == 1].sample(frac = 0.6)
    return a.append(b)
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('ZZONE').apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  ZZONE  ZRET_QTY  ZREQ_VAL  ACTIVE
0   BLR       125     25.66       1
1   BOM       223     29.56       1
```

Comment: okay so dont you think if there are four pairs for BLR ZZONE, like two 1's and 0's respectively, this will fail, as OP says "equal number of 1 and 0 are present"

Comment: @iamklaus - yop, I add solution for this

Comment: @jezrael: Great. What if I use different `frac` in `sample` function. Lets say for `ACTIVE` 1 I use `sample(frac=0.6)` and for `ACTIVE` 0 I use `sample(frac = 0.4)`

Comment: Yes, I got the same. In fact I used `a.append(b)` in my case and then I saw your edit. Thank You. Much appreciated.